# Updating attribute table from an Excel file using Python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, attribute-table, excel

I am kinda new to Python, please excuse for such a trivial questions. There is a shapefile (let's call it Materials.shp). I have an attribute table with different fields (for example, windows, doors, etc..). The script I am trying to write needs to update the values for those fields. The new values for those fields I get are from an Excel file. Is it possible to do that? What is the easiest way for the script to update the values of these cells? I am using ArcGIS for Desktop.

Comment: Join the table and use calculate field. Joining http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000002n000000 calculate field http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004m000000 Your field names will change to <shapefile>.field and <excel_table>.field just to keep them separate. Ideally you would import the excel into access (personal geodatabase) format first. Note: there are strict requirements on excel files as tables see: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000001w000000

Comment: Would you be able to let us know whether you are using ArcGIS for Desktop, QGIS or another GIS software product by using the **edit** button beneath your question, please?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to read the Excel file with Python. It depends on the version of the excel file. I used xlrd in the past and it was really simple.

In this page: http://www.python-excel.org/ There's a list of modules that you can try to read the data in the spreadsheet. Documentation for each one is included there. You might find this useful  at least for that part of your task.